# Dispise all efforts, open graph is a total mess

Tags: seo

I created this WordPress/Fizz theme/Woocommerce shop: http://jexiste.clothing/ Now I'd like to share it on Facebook and on other social networks but the Open Graph is a total mess: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fjexiste.clothing%2F I tried fixing it with Yoast SEO and other plugins but there's always a problem. So I deactived and deleted all the SEO-related plugins. I added the info in the head section of the Fizz theme's header.php using the WordPress dashboard editor but it won't help.

I'd like to force Facebook using this image when publishing the main page ( http://jexiste.clothing/): http://jexiste.clothing/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/fb.jpg. I want Facebook to use the article's photo when publishing an article page (http://jexiste.clothing/product/hologram-sticker-pack/ for example). The description should be the same as the published page's one.

What should I do? I tried everything. There must be a code somewhere I can edit or so...

Thank you in advance and happy 2018 to you all!

Comment: This is not a question specific to core Wordpress functionality and therefore is not appropriate for this forum unfortunately. I would try stackoverflow perhaps, but you'll need to post some examples of code you've tried over there to actually get some help. Best of luck.

Comment: @Eckstein this question is more relevant here than in a forum for generic PHP etc questions.  The question refers to header.php (WP specific, and typically where og and meta tags will be "added") and a Wordpress specific solution is required e.g. `add_action('wp_head'` and/or how to get relevant text for tags from WP and the sites installed plugins/DB. I was going to answer this myself until I discovered the site uses Woocommerce (of which I have no knowledge).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is `Missing Properties` - "The following required properties are missing: `fb:app_id`". You need to add an `fb:app_id`.

I also see an error for `Extraneous properties specified`. "The following properties are specified on the webpage but NOT supported for the specified `og:type : fb:admin`